# Apache Airflow - Cannot setup Airflow on CentOS7 -

Tags: docker, sqlite, airflow, centos7

I'm trying to run Apache Airflow using a container CentOS7. I am running using Python 3.6.9. I already install apache airflow using pip but when I try to setup the database using `airflow initdb` I get the following error:

```
(app-root) sh-4.2$ airflow version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app-root/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 37, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1007, in <module>
    conf.validate()
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 209, in validate
    self._validate_config_dependencies()
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 246, in _validate_config_dependencies
    raise AirflowConfigException(f"error: cannot use sqlite version < {min_sqlite_version}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite version < 3.15.0
```

What Can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade your sqlite version:

```
yum update
yum install sqlite
```

Example with `docker run -it centos:latest`:

```
[root@d09e5ee37969 /]# sqlite3 --version
3.26.0 2018-12-01 12:34:55 bf8c1b2b7a5960c282e543b9c293686dccff272512d08865f4600fb58238alt1
```

Airflow >=2.0.0 only works with Sqlite 3.15.0+

Comment: Hi @kaxil If we want to use postgresql do we have to still install Sqlite 3.15.0+?

Comment: Nope, if you are using a Postgres or MySQL, you don't need to install Sqlite at all

Comment: Thank you. But interestingly I am getting sqlite error depicted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369558/airflow-exceptions-airflowconfigexception-error-cannot-use-sqlite-version-3)

Comment: That basically means that you might have set the `sql_alchemy_conn` config. Run `airflow config list | grep sql_alchemy_conn` to verify