# airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite version < 3.15.0

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, airflow, psycopg2

I set up my airflow (2.0.1) postgresql conection according to [airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html)
But when I try to use it tells me I should have Sqlite > 3.15.0. It is so difficult to upgrade sqlite on Centos7. Even so why should I use and need sqlite?

```
(airflow) [root@airflow02 ~]# sudo -u airflow /opt/airflow/bin/airflow db check
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/airflow/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
        from airflow.__main__ import main
      File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
        from airflow import settings
      File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 37, in <module>
        from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
      File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1007, in <module>
        conf.validate()
      File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 209, in validate
        self._validate_config_dependencies()
      File "/opt/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 246, in _validate_config_dependencies
        raise AirflowConfigException(f"error: cannot use sqlite version < {min_sqlite_version}")
    airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite version < 3.15.0
```

Comment: What are the contents of `sql_alchemy_conn`? You can retrieve this with `airflow config get-value core sql_alchemy_conn`

Comment: Hi @rfkortekaas  `sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@192.168.206.9/airflow_db`

Comment: Strange, if you look in `configuration.py` you will see that it checks if `SQLite` is present in the connection string. Maybe add some debugging prints around the error lines to see why it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that there is more than one `airflow.cfg` file. As [airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html#:%7E:text=The%20first%20time%20you%20run,change%20any%20of%20the%20settings.) says: "*The first time you run Airflow, it will create a file called airflow.cfg in your $AIRFLOW_HOME directory (~/airflow by default).*"

So when I start web-server pointing out to PostgreSQL configured `airflow.cfg`, error disappeared. It didn't make sense although using PostgreSQL why getting SQLite error. Now I understand that I was trying to start webserver using another raw `airflow.cfg` which doesn't contain postgresql `sql_alchemy_conn`. Raw airflow.cfg contains default sql_alchemy_conn for SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue when running Airflow for development purpose. Only difference is I didn't point to use different db but was running in default sqlite supported by Airflow. I am posting this reply so that it will be useful for someone who reaches to this question with stack trace logs.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.2/howto/set-up-database.html#setting-up-a-sqlite-database), minimum version of sqlite support is 3.15.0

In my case, the sqlite version installed is 3.41.0, but still I got this issue as the python interpreter used by Airflow might still use the older version available in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (as mentioned in the docs)

So simply setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and starting the Airflow fixed the issue for me.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set AIRFLOW_HOME. Then you can prevent this issue.

export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow